# add onclick action to mathml

Tags: javascript, html, mathml

I'm trying to add some actions to be executed when the arrows in following page are clicked:

```html
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


 <script type="text/javascript">

  function createActions() {
   var div = document.getElementById("l");
   div.onclick=function(){alert("HI")};
  }

  
  window.onload = createActions;
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <math>
  <mn>12</mn>
  <mo>&#x00D7;<!-- × --></mo>
  <mi>a</mi>
  <munderover>
   <mo>=</mo>
   <mo id="l" style="color: red;">&rarr;</mo>
   <mo style="color: red;">&larr;</mo>
  </munderover>
  <mi>24</mi>
 </math>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Debugger shows that element "l" is returned by the call to "getElementById", but the definition of the "onclick" attribute does nothing.

In addition to previous test, I've also tested without javascript and with the mathml:

```
<mo onclick='alert("HI")'>&rarr;</mo>
```

also without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [addEventListener() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

```js
count = 1;
document.getElementById("l").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("You clicked "+ count++ +" times");
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

 <math>
  <mn>12</mn>
  <mo>&#x00D7;<!-- × --></mo>
  <mi>a</mi>
  <munderover>
   <mo>=</mo>
   <mo id="l" style="color: red;">&rarr;</mo>
   <mo style="color: red;">&larr;</mo>
  </munderover>
  <mi>24</mi>
 </math>
   
</body>
</html>
```